# How to replace input values with new values accordingly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

just want to ask if how can I set a default values according to the number of checkboxes available. For example I have 3 checkboxes and I want to have a default values of *0,0,0* since I have 3 checkboxes. And if the user click the first checkbox the first *0* will be replaced with *1* since the value of the first checkbox has a value of *1* and the same as the rest checkboxes. And if the user uncheck the first checkbox it will return to it's default value which is *0*. I have embedded my snippet. Thank you guys in advance.

```js
$('input#category').on('change', function () {
        var selectedCategories = $('.category:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        $('#post_category').val(selectedCategories);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="category" name="category" class="category category_1">Category 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="category" name="category" class="category category_2">Category 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="category" name="category" class="category category_3">Category 3
<br />
<h5>Result:</h5>
<input type="text" id="post_category">
```

Comment: You should have html elements with unique `id` attribute.. Check that `id="category"` is multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing it, just check if the boxes are checked inside the mapping

```js
var elems = $('.category[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var selectedCategories = elems.map(function() {
        return this.checked ? +this.value : 0;
    }).get();

    $('#post_category').val(selectedCategories);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="category1" name="category" class="category category_1">Category 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="category2" name="category" class="category category_2">Category 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="category3" name="category" class="category category_3">Category 3
<br />
<h5>Result:</h5>
<input type="text" id="post_category">
```

Note the selector change. You can have the same classname for all three inputs, **but they can not** have the same ID, as ID's are unique

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful one. It's working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @johnlopev: No need to make a map/iterate over all the checked checkbox inputs because the changed element checkbox have properties `value` and `checked`.. Check my answer

Comment: These answer is wrong: Not fixed the multiple elements with the same `id` attribute... and also is setting 1 on the event handler but should be the value of the element according to the question

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your code you have multiple elements with the same `id` and `name` attributes and should be unique.

On the `change` event handler there is no need to make a map/iterate over all the checked checkbox inputs because the changed element checkbox have properties `value` and `checked`:

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0],
    setPostCategory = function() {
      arr[this.value - 1] = (this.checked) ? this.value : 0;
      $('#post_category').val(arr.join(', '));
    };

$('input.category').on('change', setPostCategory);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="category1" class="category">Category 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="category2" class="category">Category 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="category3" class="category">Category 3

<br>

<h5>Result:</h5>
<input type="text" id="post_category" value="0, 0, 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#post_category').empty();

$('#post_category').val(selectedCategories);